# Gamma ray lasers?

Tags: nuclear-physics, laser, gamma-rays

Is it really possible in the foreseeable future to create a gamma ray laser? I've read these two articles on Wikipedia:

- [The hafnium controversy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafnium_controversy)
- [Induced gamma emission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_gamma_emission)

It sounds pretty amazing, although apparently no one has reproduced the phenomenon since 1998.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of research is financed by the military. You will never hear much about it. In France, even for atomic laser research, any paper to be published must first go through the hands of a military scientist.

In my country, 65% of physics research is financed by the armed forces. The heads of many large nuclear research centers have been educated in a military school (polytechnique), one of them even was a general. Alexander Grothendieck, one of the brightest French mathematicians of the 20th century, resigned and quit research because of this funding scheme.